# Confusion with malloc through function argument

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, parameter-passing

Today I was trying to code something and i found my self at some point that i need to allocate a block of memory needed for a pointer. The program was OK and checked with `valgrind` was also OK.

Some how after I started to review the whole code i realized that what i did, was that the memory was allocated for `int a` which is not a pointer.

I'm a person which learn `C` just for fun, I read some books and hundreds of Tutorials, but i never saw any mention about something like this so I really need an Explanation here.

I tried to make a small program to explain the context:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void createMe(int *a);
void freeMe(int *b);

int main(void){
    int a;
    createMe(&a);
}

void createMe(int *ptr){
    ptr = malloc(256);
    *ptr = 10;
    printf("A = %d\n",*ptr);
    freeMe(ptr);
}

void freeMe(int *ptr){
    free(ptr);
}
```

Here i have `int a` and i passed its address in `createMe(&a);`

The create function takes a pointer as argument so i had to use `&a`.
Now comes the strange part for me:

inside `createMe();` i call `malloc` on that pointer `ptr` which is the argument of the function.
Where exactly it is that memory block added/used in the pointer which is the argument of `create()` function or it sent to `a` inside main?

As far as I read/learn until now:

1) `a` doesn't get that memory block because `a` is an `int` and not an `int*`.

2) does the function argument `ptr` get that memory block`?, if so, how comes that i never read something like that.

I used `Linux mint 17.3` with `GCC-4.8.5` and `GCC-5.2.0`

Here is the result of `Valgrind`:

```
==6793== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6793== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6793== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6793== Command: ./program
==6793== 
A = 10
==6793== 
==6793== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6793==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6793==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 256 bytes allocated
==6793== 
==6793== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6793== 
==6793== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6793== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see the memory allocation takes place and `free` takes place too.

And the `GCC Flags` are:

```
-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -std=c11 -O0 -g
```

Comment: Hint: `a` is not needed here at all. Try passing `NULL`. It'll work just as well.

Comment: @cad Thank you for your response. Me I was asking if is possible to create a block of memory for a function argument. I never read something like that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of your code,

```
void createMe(int *ptr){
    ptr = malloc(256);
    *ptr = 10;
    printf("A = %d\n",*ptr);
    freeMe(ptr);
}
```

all the time, `ptr` is local to your function `createMe()`. Whatever you do to `ptr` (notice, not `*ptr`) itself, is not going to make any effect to `a`, anyway.

What you're doing here is

1. Getting a pointer type variable (as a function argument), fine.
2. Allocating memory dynamically, fine.

   2.1. Not checking for `malloc()` success, bad.
3. Using the allocated memory properly, fine.
4. Releasing the memory, fine.

You don't have any issues in your function, it's ok.

Just to elaborate, you're using `ptr` *just as another local variable* in `createMe()` function. The first `malloc()` allocates new memory block to `ptr`, anyway.

Comment: This means that you can add a memory block for a pointer which is argument of a function? I never read about that.

Comment: Like i said, was just created a small program, I always check a pointer for NULL. The Question was clearly i hope :)

Comment: Based of your Answer I can call that function on any variable which is `int` and it will not harm something. Did i understood right?

Comment: @Michi Yes, you're right, as long as you keep this function definition unchanged. :)

Comment: Yes, it is. I have to wait 5 minutes to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In C, arguments are passed by value. `ptr` in `createMe` points to new location after

```
ptr = malloc(256);
```

Now `ptr` is pointing to the beginning of a new memory chunk.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the same thing I was thinking too, that `ptr` points to a new location, but i was confused, when i saw, that through that pointer i still can update the value of `a` inside `main`.

Comment: @Michi; No. Once `ptr` is updated, it has no information about location of `a`.